# BATCH set varibale in if statement when value equals Y

Tags: file, batch-file

I have searched the forum and see this question asked often but I can not seem to get it to work for me. I am trying to set a variable when a value equals Y.  Here is what I think should work but  mer2 is not being set.

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (C:\SOMEFILE.txt) do (
set var=%%A
set mer1=!var:~0,1!
if "!mer1!"=="Y" (
set mer2=!1.5!
)
set "y=!mer1!,!mer2!"
echo !y!>>C:\SOMENEWFILE.csv
)
```

MY input file looks like this

```
Y
Y
N
N
Y
```

My expected output is this:

```
Y,1.5
Y,1.5
N,
N,
Y,1.5
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `set mer2=!1.5!` - are you sure, the variable `!1.5!` is defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two issues: `set mer2=!1.5!` should probably be `set mer2=1.5` and you never undefine it, so once you met a  `Y`, `1.5` will be added to each following line.
I'd do it a bit different (using just one variable in the loop is enough):

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
(for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (SOMEFILE.txt) do (
set var=%%A
set var=!var:~0,1!
if "!var!"=="Y" (echo Y,1.5) else echo !var!,
))>C:\SOMENEWFILE.csv
```

Redirecting the whole loop in one go is a lot faster than writing each and every single line (you won't notice it on a small file, but on a big file, it can sum up to a factor of 100 and more. (I once had a factor of >1000 with a really big file)